# Library not found Error when simple building web socket chat in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, websocket, socketrocket

i downloaded  simple web socket chat code and am getting this error

```
  ld: library not found for -lPods-SocketRocket
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please anyone tell me how to solve this?

In my other linker flags contains these things

[link](http://postimg.org/image/ev9f8qywh/)

[My code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6caVk8MnBVaWXdJS2g5VVlyWHc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: you are using this https://github.com/square/SocketRocket

Comment: yes am using that one

Comment: have you added -ObjC to your "other linker flags" option

Comment: yes it is there already

Comment: can you share your code so that i look on that.

Comment: ok, i will put that in github

Comment: please check updated question i have added "link" for my code

Comment: close your WebsocketExampleClient.xcodeproj and open WebsocketExampleClient.xcworkspace

Comment: its not working same error

Comment: in my case it works used your code

Comment: nothing just close xcodeproj and open build xcworkspace

Answer (score 0):

It seems like its not getting the path right of some of the library used here.

Do 1 thing:

- Go to Targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with library -> Add library.

**Note:**

- Make sure remove the old path before this process from Library search path

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: @NaveenKumar than what is this : -lPods-SocketRocket